# User->Email api authentication with one to many relationship in laravel 9

Tags: laravel

I want to do an authentication, a `user` from the `users` table can authenticate through several emails it has from the `emails` table.

Please give me an example. Now I started to study Laravel

##### My class User

```php
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject, MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
  
    protected $fillable = [
        'nickname',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];
   
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];
  
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
     
    public function emails(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Email::class);
    }
}
```

##### My class Email

```php
class Email extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
   
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'email',
        'HashExpire'
    ];

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to try something, this is a not a tutorials site, here we help based on what you have, what you expect, what is the output, and what you have done to try to achieve it...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```php
/**
 * Handle an authentication attempt.
 */
public function authenticate(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'password' => ['required'],
    ]);

    $email = Email::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if ($email) {
       $credentials = [
           'id' => $email->user_id,
           'email' => $request->email
       ];

       if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
          $request->session()->regenerate();
          return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
       }
    }

    return back()->withErrors([
        'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
    ])->onlyInput('email');
}
```